# Trying to use <Action> to update a control

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to use an  method to update a StatusStripLabel in a windows form.  Specifically, for the moment, all I want to do is test being able to update that label when the user clicks the button.  The code I have is this (very simple):

```
namespace CardReader
{
    public partial class frmRead : Form
    {
        public frmRead()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StatusUpdate((Button)sender,"Stand by...");
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void btnProcess_StatusUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { }

        private void frmRead_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnProcess.StatusUpdate = p => this.tsStatus.Text = p.ToString();
        }

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public Action<Button, string> StatusUpdate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the `frmRead_Load` event, the error in Visual Studio 2015 says:
"Button does not contain a definition for StatusUpdate and no extension method for StatusUpdate containing a first argument of type Button could be found."

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think we need to see where `btnProcess` is declared and instantiated. Apparently `btnProcess` is not an instance of `frmRead`.

Comment: Well, you have added the Action `StatusUpdate` to a `frmRead` object. I believe that the type of `btnProcess` is a Button and not a `frmRead`. So this is reason why `btnProcess` has no idea what `StatusUpdate` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your `StatusUpdate` action is in the Form, not the button.

Second, your action is defined as:

```
public Action<Button, string> StatusUpdate { get; set; }
```

Which matches a function:

```
void StatusUpdate(Button b, string s){}
```

but you're only assigning a one parameter anonymous function here:

```
btnProcess.StatusUpdate = p => this.tsStatus.Text = p.ToString();
```

All together it should be:

```
this.StatusUpdate = (p, s) => this.tsStatus.Text = p.ToString();
```

Comment: That fixed it, 'theB'!  Except I had to change it from p.ToString() to s.ToString() in order to print out the text.